# javascript won't work in asp.net usercontrol

Tags: asp.net

I have this control inside another control 'MyFirstControl'.

I have an alert('test') just to keep my question simple. This alert doesn't show up.
My actual javascript has many functions, but I removed all of them and put this alert just to see if it hits. But it doesn't.

I even tried `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, didn't work either.

MyDataGrid.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyDataGrid.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyAsp.Controls.MyDataGrid" %>

<script language="javascript">
alert('test');
</script>

    <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="Grid" AutoGeneratecolumns="false">
      <MasterTableView EditMode="InPlace">
        <columns>
          <telerik:GridBoundcolumn DataField="column1" HeaderText="column1">
          </telerik:GridBoundcolumn>
          <telerik:GridBoundcolumn DataField="column2" HeaderText="column2">
          </telerik:GridBoundcolumn>
        </columns>
      </MasterTableView>
      <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true"></Selecting>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true"></Scrolling>
      </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Is any part of the `MyDataGrid.ascx` UserControl being rendered?

Comment: Yeah, I have few more <input> controls, they show up.

Comment: can you post the rendered page markup?

Comment: Could there be a javascript error elsewhere on the page that's preventing this alert from running? Try loading the page with javascript debugging enabled in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need associate this alert in an event.

Try create a method to call "alert" and associate this method in an event of control.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: To trigger the alert, you will need an event.
Example:
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="Grid" AutoGeneratecolumns="false" onload="alert()">

Try it.

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can call 
`<script language="javascript">
   $(document).load(
     function () {
       alert('test');
     }
   );
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

the example by rcjuliano will not work if you are not using JQuery.

your snippet for the alert should work:

> ```
> <script language="javascript">
> alert('test');
> </script>
> ```

IDK if you are omitting the HTML tag in this for brevity but if its not inside an HTML tag is not going to work with or without JQuery

If you want rcjuliano example to work you can add the JQuery library as simple as adding this tag

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```